# PHP generate file for download then redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a PHP app that creates a CSV file which is forced to download using headers.  Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
echo $content;
exit();
```

What I'd like to do is redirect users to a new page after the file is built and the download prompt is sent.  Just adding `header("Location: /newpage")` to the end didn't work, expectedly, so I'm not sure how to rig this up.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I don't think this can be done - although I am not 100% sure.

The common thing (e.g. in popular download sites) is the reverse: first you go to the *after* page and then the download starts.

So redirect your users to the *final* page that (among other things) says:

Your download should start automatically. If not click `[a href="create_csv.php"]here[/a]`.

As about initiating the download (e.g. automatically calling create_csv.php) you have many options:

- HTML: `[meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://site/create_csv.php"]`
- Javascript: `location.href = 'http://site/create_csv.php';`
- iframe: `[iframe src="create_csv.php"][/iframe]`

Comment: How to do this as initiating was already started and drupal is already showing a page? What is the code of the javascript?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It specifically asks how to redirect to a different page after the download. If it can't be done with PHP alone, a solution Javascript with JavaScript should be suggested.

Answer (score 15):

very easy to do in the case it is really needed.

But you will need to have a bit work in JavaScript and cookies:

in PHP you should add setting up a cookie

```
header('Set-Cookie: fileLoading=true');
```

then on the page where you call the download you should track with JS (e.g. once per second) if there is coming cookie like that (there is used plugin [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) here):

```
setInterval(function(){
  if ($.cookie("fileLoading")) {
    // clean the cookie for future downoads
    $.removeCookie("fileLoading");

    //redirect
    location.href = "/newpage";
  }
},1000);
```

Now if the file starts to be downoaded JS recognizes it and redirects to the page needed after cookie is deleted.

Of course, you can tell you need browser to accept cookies, JavaScript and so on, but it works.

Answer (score 10):

The header you are sending are HTTP headers. The browser takes that as a page request and processes it as a page. And in your case, a page it needs to download.

So adding a redirect header to that confuses the whole process of downloading the file (since headers are collected, generated into one header and then sent to the browser, you can try this by setting multiple redirect headers IIRC)

Answer (score 4):

This is quite old issue, but here is how I achieved it via JS.

```
// Capture the "click" event of the link.
var link = document.getElementById("the-link");
link.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  // Stop the link from doing what it would normally do.
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Open the file download in a new window. (It should just
  // show a normal file dialog)
  window.open(this.href, "_blank");
  // Then redirect the page you are on to whatever page you
  // want shown once the download has been triggered.
  window.location = "/thank_you.html";
}, true);
```

Via - https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/463652/page-not-redirecting-after-sending-headers-in-php

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't redirect after the file was generated as the question asked, instead it redirects immediately. So if the download changes data which should be displayed in the redirected page it wont work.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind, however, the automatic initiation of downloadable files for IE users will trigger the security warning tab.  All three of the methods outlined by daremon would show this warning.  You simply can't get around this.  You will be better served if you provide real links.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
    function force_file_download($filepath, $filename = ''){
        if($filename == ''){
            $filename = basename($filepath);
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\""); 
        readfile($filepath); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)  
    }

    force_file_download('download.txt');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    location = 'page2.php'
</script>
```

Here is a solution using javascript.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Yeah, you force the file to be downloaded using php, once the download is in progress, the JS will evaluate and cause a redirect to another page (as the original question asked)

Comment: Did you test this? This looks as if the script tag at the end will be part of (appended to) the downloaded file and nothing will be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

I found one workaround for this that relies on javascript, so it's not exactly secure, but for non-secure critical sites it seems to work.

Have a form with a button titled 'download' with the action set to point to the download script, then using javascript put something on the onsubmit handler that strips out the download button and replaces the messaging on the screen. The download should still happen and the screen will change. Obviously, if there's an issue with the download script then it still looks like the download was successful even if it doesn't fire, but it's the best I've got right now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** New Solution:

```
<a id="download-link" 
   href="https://example.com/uploads/myfile.pdf" 
   class="btn">Download</a>
```

---

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(  ) {
        jQuery("#download-link").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            var _filename = url.split('/');
            _filename = _filename[_filename.length - 1];
            console.log(_filename);
        
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
            })
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(response => {
                const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = _filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            });
        
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax/61313254#61313254)

**Old answer:**

Here is the answer:
It's work!
You need three different parts of code:

**HTML**

```
<a id="download_btn" class="btn btn-primary" href="?file=filename&download=1">Download<&/a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#download_btn').click(function(){
    window.location.href = '<?=base_url()?>/?file=<?=$file;?>&download=1';
}).focusout (function(){
    window.location.href = '<?=base_url()?>';
    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
        if(isset($_GET['download']) && isset($_GET['file'])){
            
            $zip_path = 'path_to/'.$_GET['file'].'.zip';

            if(file_exists($zip_path)){
                header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_path).'"');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_path));
                header('Location: '.$zip_path);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think if you "focusout" before the download has started, the download will not start at all.

Comment: I found great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax/61313254#61313254

Answer (score 1):

You can try and redirect to the URL plus a parameter that represents the file contents. And in the redirect, you can output the file content for download.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the PHP file which contains the CSV download using:

```
<a onclick="popoutWin(\'csvexport.php\')" >Download CSV File</a>
```

or

```
<input name="newThread" type="button" value="Download CSV File"
        onclick="popoutWin(\'csvexport.php\')" />
```

where the JavaScript function `popoutWin` is

```
/*
 * Popout window that self closes for use with downloads
 */
function popoutWin(link){
    var popwin = window.open(link);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        popwin.close();
    }, 500);
}
```

This will open a window, to display the CSV download prompt and then immediately close the window, leaving only the prompt.

Comment: Note that you may need to increase the popoutWin() time to a larger value like 5000 if the php code (csvexport.php above) takes time to run, otherwise the window will close before the script has completed and the user will not be given the opportunity to select the directory to save the export file.

Comment: It's incredibly unwise to use a random time variable like that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @jvakuiler - I would be pleased to better understand why not. Please point me in the right direction and if need be, I will remove this proposed approach once I understand your advice.

Comment: Hey @Clinton thanks for your message, I'm happy to elaborate. 

First of all, you cannot assume that the window being opened will load in 500ms like you suggested. Generally speaking, you cannot assume that the window will be successfully opened at all, in any amount of time. The download can also fail leaving the user with no information besides a broken anchor.

Comment: I guess the trick would be to use a window that closes itself as soon as it is finished loading. The Javascript for this could be a bit difficult though.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm...

Put the code below in the main javascript of the site.

```
 if (window.location.pathname == '/url_of_redirect/') {
        window.open(location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/url_of_download.zip', '_parent');
    }
```

Explaining:
It does the normal redirect with php to some url you will difine and in javascipt it says: If the pathname is the same as the path that redirect made '/url_of_redirect/' then it opens the url on a new page, generating the downlod.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses php session and works without problems of any popup blockers:

**index.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['download'])) {
    echo '<p>Download in progress...</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab/12539054#comment16884210_12539054
    echo '<script>
setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = "'.$_SESSION['download'].'";
}, 3000);                          
</script>'.PHP_EOL;

    unset($_SESSION['download']);
}
?>
<a href="download.php">download</a>
```

**download.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

// create file.zip

$_SESSION['download'] = 'file.zip';

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804706/3929620
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it without cookies, sessions or multiple crazy redirects...

1. Add target="_blank" to your download button so that your download.php opens in a new window automatically as shown below.

   Download Now
2. Add an onclick function that starts a timeout counter x seconds after the download button is clicked that redirects the parent page with the download button on it to any url you want.

```js
function redirect(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.location = "your-PARENT-redirect-url";
    }, 4000);
}
```

```html
<a onClick="redirect();" target="_blank" href="url_to_your_download_file">Download Now</a>
```

The reason why you have a timeout is because you have to give the browser time to initiate the download and load _blank before redirecting the parent page. If you redirect the parent page BEFORE the _blank download page loads then the download page won't register as opened in the browser because the parent doesn't match the child.

Once the browser establishes a connection from user to download file, the parent page will automatically redirect! In short, open your download page directly with your link using target="_blank" and then redirect the parent after _blank loads.

Here is the PHP for your download.php using readfile and headers, change the headers for the type of file you want to serve and your good to go!

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=your-whatever-file.pdf");
readfile("your-whatever-file.pdf");
```

No trickery just good ole common sense!