# Redirect any page after file download in php

Tags: php

My code is:

```
readfile('cls_ref.csv');
fclose($fp);
$file_type   = 'octet-stream';
$file_name   = "cls_ref_" . date('m-d-Y H:i');
$file_ending = "csv";
header("Content-Type: application/$file_type; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.$file_ending");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Location:index.php");
```

I want to redirect after download to `index.php` but it is redirect before download.

I write a code `header("Location:index.php");` at end of the file but it is redirect before
download the file.

Any solution for that?

Comment: I don't think you can redirect on the PHP file where you are printing out the file. Maybe try to redirect using javascript on the page where you have the download link? Or redirect to another php page where it starts the download and redirects using the meta tag.

Comment: Implement JQuery on your page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP generate file for download then redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect)

Comment: Make link to the file open in new window and then with javascript you can redirect user with `location.href ="index.php"`

Answer (score -3):

How about a meta refresh after 10 seconds:

```
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10;URL=index.php\">";
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT WORK!!  
it is written in `.csv` file at end of file.

Comment: Seems like he's outputting the contents of the file. Printing anything would append that to the file, thus ruining the document.