# DomPDF from database record using laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, routes, dompdf

I am using laravel 4.2 barryvdh/laravel-dompdf.
I want to have button for print my PDF.
My routes:

```
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
```

In OrderController I have method:

```
public function printpdf($id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('print.en', $order);
        return $pdf->download($order->id .' '. $order->created_at);
    }
```

I can to call that method from my `show.blade.php`. I am using this link:

`<a class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="{{URL::to('orders/' . $order->id . '/printpdf')}}">Print PDF</a>`

What route I must have to make this work? I want to make a function which takes a record from my MySQL database and prints it as PDF. How to use this correctly?

Comment: And how to pass my `$order` data to my print.en.blade.php from printpdf method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As laravel doc provided,

> If it becomes necessary for you to add additional routes to a resource
>   controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those
>   routes before your call to `Route::resource`:

In your case, you can do like this,

```
Route::get('orders/{id}/printpdf', 'OrderController@printpdf');
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
```

In your OrderController, according to [this issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/91), you can do it like this.

```
public function printpdf($id)
{
    $order = Order::find($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('print.en', array("order" => $order));
    return $pdf->download($order->id .' '. $order->created_at);
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Ok, routes are clear, now problems apears at unknown parameter $order in my view... How to pass it?

Comment: in my method var_dump($order) shows that I have all elements, but in my view, I have no info.

Comment: One last thing, how to redirect after download pop- up to homepage with message "Order saved"?

Comment: It is a little bit tricky. Because you can't send hearder twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872534/how-to-download-a-file-then-redirect-to-another-page-in-php

Comment: So, After download Myview stays show.blade.php. So solution could be:
1. To add button and redirect?

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest way. But you can redirect by using that way. http://www.willmaster.com/blog/automation/one-link-download-and-redirect.php But it has to write pdf file first.

Comment: How how to inform user, that he already printed a view? add value for order in database?

Comment: You can set flag in user session before download pdf. According to that flag, you can prevent downloading it and add value to db again.