# Codeigniter redirect after force download

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a public function that downloads a JSON file. I would like it to redirect to the index (`base_url`) after the download is complete. I tried using the `ob_start` and `ob_flush` PHP functions but that doesn't do it. Is this possible?

```
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['events'] = $this->events_model->get_events();

    ob_start();
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='EVENTS.json'"); 

    echo json_encode($data);
    ob_flush();

    redirect(base_url());
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect)?

Comment: You can not deliver download data _and_ redirect in the same HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

function redirect() does not work after 'echo';

**before** redirect you can't echo anything in browser

please comment this row:

```
//echo json_encode($data);
```