# How to track form submission in IE with bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that the user fills out and gets submitted through jquery using $("form").submit();

while the form is submitted I use a modal window from the twitter bootstrap library to disable the entire screen and tell the user that the form is being submitted.

My problem is that when the form submit is complete, a pdf file is downloaded to the client's machine as a response is some cases, 
If this is the case, the user approves the download and the form is stuck with the modal window covering the entire page and I look like an idiot, because the user can't go on using the web page.

I've tried using a $("form").submit() ".success()" function, but when I use that, the jquery fails and the page ceases to function.

The only thing that I can think of that's useful is the fact that the progress bar at the bottom of the browser in IE runs and only closes when the pdf file download request pops up.

Is there anyway I can intercept the progress of the form submission, and close the modal window at the moment when the form is done submitting?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few weeks back and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732) helped. Basically you have to redirect your user to a page which will also handle the downloading of the PDF.