# Yii automatic generate report when data has been saved

Tags: php, yii

How do I get when it finishes inserting the data, perform direct application automatically generates reports based on the data that has just inputted ?

My controller (Save) :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new PurchaseOrder;

    if(isset($_POST['PurchaseOrder']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['PurchaseOrder'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect('index');
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

My controller (Generate Report) :

```
public function actionCetak()
{
    if(isset($_POST['PrintPO'])){
        $data = $_POST['no_po'];
        if($data==''){
            return false;
        }else{
            $HTML2PDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
            $HTML2PDF->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('data_print', array(
                'data' => $this->loadCetak($data)
            ), true));
            $HTML2PDF->Output();
        }
    }else{
        $this->render('form_cetak_po'); 
    }
}
```

both functions run smoothly, but when I `combining` into :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new PurchaseOrder;

    if(isset($_POST['PurchaseOrder']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['PurchaseOrder'];
        if($model->save())
            $HTML2PDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
            $HTML2PDF->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('data_print', array(
                'data' => $this->loadCetak($model->id)
            ), true));
            $HTML2PDF->Output();
            $this->redirect('index');
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Application only do the insert function. How do I order when finished doing the insert, directly akang application and the data it generates can be downloaded.

Thanks

Comment: by the way, `ePdf ` is an extension ? or native yii ?

Comment: this code always redirects after successful save, remove redirect

Comment: ePdf is extension. But how I redirect after generate? I have to go back to reload the page

Answer (score 0):

You misses brackets after `if(save())`

Look at this :

```
 if(isset($_POST['PurchaseOrder']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['PurchaseOrder'];
        if($model->save())
            { // <-- add this
            $HTML2PDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
            $HTML2PDF->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('data_print', array(
                'data' => $this->loadCetak($data)
            ), true));
            $HTML2PDF->Output();

            } //<-- add this
            else
             {
              $this->redirect('index');
             }
    }
```

Comment: No change. just saved

Comment: Success. But I have to go back to reload the page view `index`

Comment: I think you cant redirect after download

Answer (score 0):

### **Redirecting after download**

I don't think this can be done.

The common thing  in popular download sites  is the reverse: first you go to the "after" page and then the download starts.

You can do this :

after save,redirect to something like this
`index.php?r=controller/index&file_info=information`

and in index method, check `if ($_GET['file_info'])`, then create your pdf file and make the download.

[**Look at the top answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732)