# CSV File not downloading codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, csv, cookies

I have an array like that

```
$csvDownload=Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [serial] => Serial
                [volume] => Tanksize
                [manufacturer] => Manufacturer
                [manufacturerDate] => manufacturerDate
                [warehouse] => Warehousename
                [pickLocation] => PickupLocation
                [pickDate] => pickDate
                [CompanyName] => Company
                [nationalBoard] => nationalBoard
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [serial] => 20001
                [volume] => 120H
                [manufacturer] => Atlas
                [manufacturerDate] => 2013
                [warehouse] => WAREHOUSE1
                [pickLocation] => kanpur
                [pickDate] => 2/25/2014
                [CompanyName] => WIM
                [nationalBoard] => he
            )
        );
```

what i need to do is

1)download csv

2)after then return $data to controller
   if i use **Exit** after the code before return it works **download the csv file** but session do not print.
 if i remove **exit**  from code session message print but csv do not download

```
Please help what i am doing wrong or any way to solve this..!
I need both session flash as well as download the csv file.
```

**I have sample code**

```
In controller
```

```
function downloadErrorCSV()
    {$data=$this->tankmodel->downloadcsv();    $this->session->set_flashdata('successAddBulkTank','success');
    redirect('mypage');}
```

**In model** i have

```
{some code of model} and $data='sucess'{code of download csv} and then return $data;
```

Now if i place exit after csv download script csv it get downloaded and if remove exit;it do not download the csv  I need both 
**download** csv and 
**show** success message as well.

Comment: this may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate your code of **downloading** and **saving data**.

I believe you don't have to save error file at server. and use javascript code to download that file.

don't download file immediately using this code <strike>$data=$this->tankmodel->downloadcsv();</strike>. save it first at server then download it later after showing message.

Saving Excel File at server: [Here](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework)

Downloading of this file you can use two ways:

- Javasctipt `location.href = 'http://sitefullpath/yourfilename';`
- iframe: `[iframe src="yourfilename"][/iframe]`

Hope this will help.

Comment: "thanks" but if i do so it takes too much time to execute i have 1000s of data to be uploaded.to uploading  the same data twice is not better idea.

Comment: @DeepakSharma i think you don't understand what i said i am not asking it two time one time is enough to save Failed data and you can download it whenever you want.

Comment: hy @deepak manwal it works for me like a charm thanks a lot.!