# redirect after using the header for download a file

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to redirect the page after downloading the file, i use two methods for redirect 1- javascript 2- header but nothing works for me , my code is

```
<?php

$packPath = $_REQUEST['packPath'];

   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Cache-Control: public');
   header('Content-Type: application/zip');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. basename($packPath));
   header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($packPath)) );
   ob_clean(); #THIS!
   flush();
   readfile($packPath);

  // header('Location: ' . $_POST['accept']);
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          window.location.href="'.$_POST['accept'].'";
      </script>'; */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You should check that `$_POST` value. Right now you're vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: i dont think that u can , whatever you put in the page will be added to the file that is being dowbloaded.

Comment: i appreciate your reply ,but i write direct the static page url this will also not work i am getting the post value of accept on this page... so its not the error of post value of accept. you can check it with static url

Comment: Send the user to the page you want to redirect to, then from that page open an external link with the file you want to download. This can be done using javascript.

Comment: can you give some example of it how can it be done by javascript.

Comment: Maybe here you find the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732 , it is a similar question