# Send file AND html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express to create a link where users download a file. Once click the link, the file downloads to their computer.

For that I'm using:

```
res.download('filename.pdf');
```

Easy.

Is is possible to either redirect them to another page or send an html page along as well?  Not sure web servers can even do this.

Comment: I haven't tried specifically in node, but usually you have to do it the other way - go to the landing page then trigger the download from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In the future, I think you could pull this off with [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) or HTTP 2.0, but HTTP 1.1 doesn't allow this.  Technically you can attach data to a 302 moved response, but the browser is just going to ignore it.