# Two headers for different url's in the same page (PHP)

Tags: php

I want to, once the user has arrived the page, first, download an item using another script and then, redirect him or her to the index.

So I have the following code:

```
$filename = $_GET["file"];

$down = 'components/com_djclassifieds/views/item/tmpl/download.php?file='.$filename;

header( "refresh:2;url=$down" );   

header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
```

And, for example, the following url:

http://my.web.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=39&file=test.pdf

But it is not working. I also tried to use 'Location' in this code:

```
$filename = $_GET["file"];

header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/components/com_djclassifieds/views/item/tmpl/download.php?file='.$filename);

exit;

header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
```

And it downloads the file but after that it does not redirect me to the index.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not possible that way. Don't waste further time on it.

Comment: Oh...ok, haha. So, how can I do something similar? I mean, first go to the script to download the item and then go to the index.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732

Comment: The thing is, how can I add a parameter to that? Because in the examples there are no parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Don't bother with the PHP.  You can do it with JQuery.

HTML:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='display:none;' id="div"></div>
<script>
var iframe = $("<iframe/>").attr({
    src: "http://example.com/path/file.extension"
}).appendTo($("#div"));
window.location="http://example.com/path/redirect.html"
</script>
```

Comment: That is not working for me but thank you anyway. I think is something about the jquery. I can never do it work.

Comment: If you want I can type up a slightly more specific example.

Comment: Ok, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `<?php
$filename = $_GET["file"];

$down = 'components/com_djclassifieds/views/item/tmpl/download.php?file='.$filename;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='display:none;' id="div"></div>
<script>
var iframe = $("<iframe/>").attr({
    src: "<?=$down?>"
}).appendTo($("#div"));
window.location="index.php"
</script>`