# How do I redirect after download in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using maatwebsite/excel library to create excel files then download my file.

In my controller I do like this:

```
  public function todas()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        if(isset($input['todos'])&&($input['todos']!=0))
        {
            set_time_limit(0);
            $datainicio = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $input['todos'])->pluck('periodo_inicio'); 
            $datafinal  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $input['todos'])->pluck('periodo_fim');
            $mes  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $input['todos'])->pluck('mes_referencia'); 

            $horarioQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
                                 ->whereBetween('data', array($datainicio, $datafinal))
                                 ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                                 ->orderBy('cod_funcionario')
                                 ->orderBy('data', 'ASC')
                                 ->get();

            $horarios = reset($horarioQuery);
            
            $count  = count($horarios);

            if($horarios==null)
                return Redirect::route('relatorios.todas')->withErrors(['não existem marcações para este período']);

            $funcionarios = $this->funcionario->all();

            $datainicio  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datainicio); 
            $datafinal   = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datafinal);

            $nome = 'Marcações'.$mes.'-'.Carbon::now()->year;
            $this->horario->allToExcel($nome, $horarios);

            return View::make('relatorios.todashow', compact('funcionarios', 'datainicio', 'datafinal', 'horarios', 'count', 'nome'));
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route('relatorios.todas')->withErrors(['Selecione um período!']);
        }
    }
```

That is my function to generate excel file  :

```
public static function allToExcel($nome, $horarios)
    {   
            Excel::create($nome , function ($excel) use ($horarios) {

            $excel->sheet('Marcações', function ($sheet) use ($horarios) {

                $sheet->row(1, array(

                            'Unidade',
                            'Nome',
                            'Função',
                            'Data',
                            'Hora Faturada',
                            'Hora Contratada',
                            'Horas Trabalhadas',
                            'Horas Extras',
                            'Tempo Exposicao',
                            'Atividade',
                            'Item Contabil',
                            'Observacoes'
                        ));

                $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                    $row->setBackground('#2A8005');
                    $row->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $row->setFontWeight('bold');
                });

                $i = 2;
                foreach ($horarios as $horario) {
                        
                        if($horario->funcionario->funcao_qt != null)
                            $funcao = $horario->funcionario->funcao_qt;
                        else   
                            $funcao = $horario->funcionario->funcao_a5;
        
                        $sheet->row($i, array(
                            $horario->unidade,
                            $horario->funcionario->nome,
                            $funcao,
                            $horario->data->format('d/m/Y'),
                            $horario->hora_faturada->format('H:i'),
                            $horario->hora_contratada,
                            $horario->getWorkedHours()->format('H:i'),
                            $horario->getExtraHours()->format('H:i'),
                            $horario->tempo_exposicao ?: "-",
                            $horario->atividade,
                            $horario->item_contabil->CTD_DESC01,
                            $horario->observacoes
                        ));
                        if($i % 2 != 0)
                        {
                        $sheet->row($i, function($row) {
                            $row->setBackground('#D1D1D1');
                            });
                        }    
                
                        $i++;
                    }
            });

            })->download('xls');
    }
```

But after I download the excel file I cant redirect to a route or view and I Also tried to use:

Routes:

```
Route::post('relatorios/todas', array('as' => 'relatorios.todas', 'after' => 'voltar', 'uses' => 'ReportsController@todas'));
```

Filter:

```
Route::filter('voltar', function()
{
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', '<p class="bg-success"><b>Relatório gerado com sucesso</b></p>');
});
```

But it didn't work anyway, is there another way to redirect after downloading my file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It cannot be done. The problem is that if you send a download instruction to the user browser, you are, as a matter of fact, sending a response and you can send only one response back.

What you could do is to, first redirect your user to the "final" page and in that page start the download. The code would be something like:

```
Session::flash('download.in.the.next.request', 'filetodownload.pdf');

return Redirect::to('/whatever/page');
```

Then in your new page you'll have some options:

- HTML: [meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://watever.com/create_csv.php"]
- Javascript: location.href = 'http://watever.com/create_csv.php';
- iframe: [iframe src="create_csv.php"][/iframe]

So you can in your layout do something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
      @if(Session::has('download.in.the.next.request'))
         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url={{ Session::get('download.in.the.next.request') }}">
      @endif
   <head>

   <body>
      ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Also, take a look at this answer: [PHP generate file for download then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732)

Comment: I'm getting stucked in a loop where always my layouts redirects to the download file. I can not unset (or dont know how) the download url

Comment: amazing. worked on me 100%, what i really did is i made a loading gif image upon button click. my controller were able to save it on the storage folder then the page redirects and download the excel file. thank you very much! `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

that worked

I gave up from using ajax and just tried with routes

```
Route::get('relatorios/exportar/{cod}', array('as' => 'relatorios.exportar', 'uses' => 'ReportsController@exportar'));
```

my controller

```
 public function exportar($cod)
    {   
        set_time_limit(0);
        $datainicio = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_inicio'); 
        $datafinal  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_fim');
        $mes  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('mes_referencia'); 

        $horarioQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
                            ->whereBetween('data', array($datainicio, $datafinal))
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->orderBy('cod_funcionario')
                            ->orderBy('data', 'ASC')
                            ->get();

        $horarios = reset($horarioQuery);

        $nome = 'Marcações'.$mes.'-'.Carbon::now()->year;

        $this->horario->allToExcel($nome, $horarios);
    }
```

view:

```
 {{ link_to_route('relatorios.exportar', 'Exportar para excel', array($cod), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```

that's solved for me, because dont load another page and download the correct file.
thx for the help!!

Comment: I am having the same issue but cannot understand your answer, can you elaborate..

Comment: This not answer the question, only you have the download in the same page.