# response and redirect on one return on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want return response that can download and a redirect that can redirect to other page on the same controller function is it possible if so how can I do it if you could show me like this code if i want to download and then redirect to other page. on one controller.

```
public function handledown()
{
    return Response::download(Input::get('book')) & Redirect::action('ViewController@book');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return multiple responses like you are trying to do there.

My advice to you would be to return the response download and then redirect to a route you define within a data-redirect attribute on your button etc what ever you use, with jQuery etc.

Another solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel).