# Laravel - Is there a way to return a view and download?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to figure out a way i can return a view but also call the download function. Something like this:

```
return view('home')->download($filename, 'text.csv', $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it's possible. Laravel has to choose what to send to your browser. If it sends a redirect header you won't see the page.

The only solution is to render the view and in the view put a simple javascript like:

```
window.location.href = "<your file url>"
```

If this is a file it should start a download without changing page.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's a way to do it using a stream download. It's not pretty, but it works. Note the function has to `echo` and not `return`, hence why `render()` is called on the view.

```
return response()->streamDownload(function() {
        echo view('home')->render();
    }
    , 'test.csv'
    , ['Content-Type' => 'text/csv']
);
```