# laravel return pdf download but still want to redirect

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, return

I'd like to ask if anyone knows any way to redirect an user if a return has already been send.

In my case I try to accomplish the following. A pdf is generated and send by the browser as a download. But after it's being send I'd still like to redirect because the database records will be updated in the process.

my code in the controller is as below:

```
session::flash('informationmessage', 'The labour entries were billed');
        return $pdf->download();
        redirect('admin/customers');
```

any help would be appreciated, cheers

Comment: Take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. For the redirection is done by client side, it's a small js code generate by server side. When the request is done, the connection is closed. Server side can not send info to browser any more.
you may try open a new tab for download and you redirect the main tab.

Comment: Alright thanks for clarifing it.I guess I will save the pdfs as a file and let the user download them elsewhere. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

In short, not possible. As you say, you have already returned a response before you get to your redirect. There

Answer (score 0):

use jquery filedownloader for downloading the file, as it work on ajax request, you can do any further processing after download whether its a new response or new request ...
for more about `http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/`