# How to Redirect After PDF Download in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How to Redirect Custom URL After PDF Download in Laravel

```
return $pdf->download('SCHOOLHIGHEREDUCATIONPASS-'.$familymemberdetails->id.'.pdf');
```

Comment: could you please share a little more information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25625653/320487