# Redirecting after exporting an excel sheet in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

How do I redirect to another page for successfully exporting a laravel view file. I am using Laravel Excel 2.1.20. 
I researched and I discovered that this can't be done except I redirect first and then download the excel sheet. But I don't know how to do this. Past solutions on this issue have not really been helpful to me.

Here is my controller:

```
$export = Excel::create('Request for Quote', function($excel) use($item, $request) {
                    $excel->sheet('RFQ 1', function($sheet) use($item, $request) {
                    $sheet->loadView('requests.send_rfq_pdf')
                                ->with('item', $item)
                                ->with('request', $request);
                    });
                })->download('xls');
```

Answer (score -1):

As the normal function you can use return view to what eve the blade template you wanna redirect.

```
return view(yourView);
```

or

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

or

```
return back()->withInput();
```

I think this will be helpful to you

Comment: It does not work. I already know this. What I said in my question is that the page does not redirect after the excel sheet has downloaded.

Comment: you can use the redirect method when you finish the excel download in the same function.

Comment: This is an answer but I dunno how to implement it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel