# How to redirect after download?

Tags: php, laravel

I have below function to download a pdf file

```
public function download($id) {
        $detail = pesanmakam::findOrFail($id);
        $name = date('YmdHis') . ".pdf";
        $data = PDF::loadView('guest/log/pdf', compact('detail'))->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf');
        return $data->download($name);
    }
```

above  download function works fine but it's just stay on the same page. Is it possible to redirect it to another page after the download succeed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel
follow this url this will help you , i think

Comment: you can use
Redirect::to('/otherpage');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP generate file for download then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

You can't because forcing download file is made with HTTP header and redirection is based on the same. So you can't do both at the same time.

You can find more information on this other topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

[Read it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

```
public function download($id) {
        $detail = pesanmakam::findOrFail($id);
        $name = date('YmdHis') . ".pdf";
        $data = PDF::loadView('guest/log/pdf', compact('detail'))->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf');
       // return $data->download($name);
        return Redirect::to($url);//$url > where u want to go
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following line just after the function call

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

suppose you called function like

```
$down = download(10);
//then just below it write like
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

instead of http://www.example.com put the page url where you want to redirect after download.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function download($id) {
        $detail = pesanmakam::findOrFail($id);
        $name = date('YmdHis') . ".pdf";
        $data = PDF::loadView('guest/log/pdf', compact('detail'))->setPaper('a4')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf');
        $data->save('folder_name/'.$name)
        return Redirect::to('url')
    }
```