# How to attach a message to download in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I would like to send a message with the download function from laravel.

What I'm currently using:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $fileName);
```

What I tried:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $fileName)->with('success','Download started!');
```

It doesn't work.

In my view:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
            <p class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
        @endif
```

Comment: use Session::has('success') instead of Session::has('message') in view.

Comment: @abhishekkumar Unfortunately not working as well. I tried withSuccess first. Don't work either.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel

Comment: Try using the global session helper instead,  `session('message')`