# Redirect after download file laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redirect, routes

**Hello there**

Hope you will be doing well.I want to redirect to a route after file download but as we know that return only works once in a controller method how i can achieve this with laravel 5.7.I have to set a session and display it when data exported in txt file.I want this with post method.
Every thing is fine but redirect is not working;

**Controller Method**

```
public function exportTxtProcess(Request $request)
{
    $table = $request->tblExportSelect;

    $destinationPath = public_path('/');

    $result;

    $outputs = DB::select("SELECT * FROM $table");

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $fileName = $table . "-" . $today;
    $fp = fopen($destinationPath . "$fileName.txt", "wb");

    foreach ($outputs as $output) {
        $output = (array)$output;

        @array_shift($output);

        $removeUserId = @$output['user_id'];
        $created_at = @$output['created_at'];
        $updated_at = @$output['updated_at'];

        if (($key = array_search($removeUserId, $output)) !== false) {
            unset($output[$key]);
        }
        if (($key1 = array_search($created_at, $output))) {

            unset($output[$key1]);
        }

        if (($key2 = array_search($updated_at, $output))) {

            unset($output[$key2]);
        }

        if (is_null($created_at) OR $created_at == '') {
            unset($output['created_at']);
        }

        if (is_null($updated_at) OR $updated_at == '') {
            unset($output['updated_at']);
        }


        $netResult = $this->getTableFields($table, $output);

        fwrite($fp, $netResult);

    }

    $result = fclose($fp);


    if ($result) {
        $pathToFile = $destinationPath . "$fileName.txt";

        $redirect = redirect()->back();
        $sess = Session::flash('success', 'Table exported successfully');
        return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);


    }

}
```

**Thank in advance**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect after download in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

> You can only have 1 response, so it's impossible to instruct a double
>   return. What you could do, is set the filename you wish to have
>   downloaded in a session variable, then redirect back to whatever page.
>   Within the redirected page, you could flash your message, along with
>   having an automatic download of the file.

Here is some threads on the topic:

[How do I redirect after download in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624927/how-do-i-redirect-after-download-in-laravel)

[PHP generate file for download then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect/822732#822732)

Comment: Sir  now i am getting this error in console.
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///