# load a new page after fpdf's output in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

i have a problem with fpdf ( another more =( )

i want to load a page after a pdf output... this is my end code:

.....

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,10,"Totale Camper Cliente: ".$TOTAL_CLIENT." euro"."\n");
$pdf->MultiCell(0,10,"Totale Complessivo: ".$TOTAL." euro"."\n");
$pdf->MultiCell(0,10,"bye!");

$pdf->Output("$client"."_2015".".pdf",'D'); 
redirect($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'index.php/site/members_area','refresh');
```

but the program create the pdf but dont go in **/site/members_area**

do you have any answer for me ?
thanks a lot 
by

Comment: Because the header output already send. try `if(
$pdf->Output("$client"."_2015".".pdf",'D') ) { redirect($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'index.php/site/members_area','refresh'); exit; }`

Comment: @TamilSelvan it doesnt work =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Outputting to screen followed by a redirect isn't the right approach. We need to separate the PDF generation as much as possible from all other code. As a quick solution, you can open a new window and generate the file there. The redirect can be handled through JavaScript bound to the child window by the parent window. Your parent window can reload itself if it detects the child window has been closed. An extremely brief jQuery example:

```
var childWindow = window.open('print.php');
$(childWindow).bind('beforeunload',function(){ location.reload(); });
```