# PHPExcel Redirect Page After Creating Excel File

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, phpexcel

I would like to know how to redirect the page after creating a file using PHPExcel.  File created is ok but redirection to another page is not.  Below are some codes.

```
$excel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$_SESSION["information"] = "Motor Line Checking Completed.";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='".$report_name.".xlsx'");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "Excel2007");
$writer -> save('php://output');
exit;
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/../../");
exit;
```

NOTES:

- If I remove `exit;`after `save();`, xlsx file will be corrupted.
- If I move `header("Location:...");`before `save();`, it will redirect but will not create xlsx.
- I also tried redirecting using javascript.

What I want is to create xlsx and redirect the page after.

Comment: you can make this excel file after redirect the page.

Comment: see here  for a reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect

Comment: Hi @AnowarCst, does that mean I have to redirect first and create the file there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to just provide a link on the redirected page. From that page I can create trigger for that link to just automatically download the file.

From the page that creates the file:

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "Excel2007");
$metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data(tmpfile());
$tmpFilename = $metaDatas['uri'];
$writer -> save($tmpFilename);
$newfile = "../outbox/".$report_name."_".substr(date("Y"), -2).date("mdhis").".xlsx";
rename($tmpFilename, $newfile);
$tmpary = explode("/", $newfile);
$_SESSION["download"] = $tmpary[count($tmpary) - 1];
$_SESSION["information"] = "File Creation Completed.";
```

From redirected page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["information"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["information"];
    if(isset($_SESSION["download"])) {
?>
    <a href="outbox/<?php echo $_SESSION["download"]; ?>">
        <button class="download" type="button">Click here to download <?php echo $_SESSION["download"]; ?> file.</button>
    </a>
<?php
    }
    session_unset();
}
?>
```

Comment: I am facing same problem, but `session` method not going to work. But  my code looks like [stackoverflow question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593588/create-formatted-excel-spreadsheet-with-mysql-data-and-php-using-tables/31594131#31594131)
Do you got me?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the beginning of the page?

Comment: I have followed another method