# create formatted excel spreadsheet with MySQL data and PHP using tables

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am working on exporting data from a MySQL database into an Excel spreadsheet. I have found code for doing this before and it works quite well. It does not format the spreadsheet. It was also the first PHP/MySQL site I created and the data didn't need to be pretty. The current project requires formatted data.

Yesterday, I found an article that may have allowed me to do what I need to do. Like an idiot, I didn't copy the link down. I can't find it today.

Here's my code -

```
<?php 
    require_once("includes/connection.php"); 
    require_once("includes/functions.php");     

    // set $closed to 0 for development
    $closed = 0;

    //create a sting to allow the user to see if s/he is looking at open or closed items
    if ($closed) {
        $filename = FILENAME."_closed"; 
    } else {
        $filename = FILENAME."_open";
    }

    // $data will hold the result
    $data = '<table>';
    // is the row a header?
    $th   = FALSE;
    // define the separator character
    $sep  = '\t';
    // array for keys
    $thKey = array();
    // are we in the first row? 
    $firstRow = TRUE;

    // create the query
    $query  = "SELECT ";
    $query .=   "training_requirements.Training, mechanism.mechName, location.locationName, impacted_employees.groupName, ";
    $query .=   "training_requirements.DateReceived, training_requirements.DateStart, training_requirements.DateDue, ";
    $query .=   "requester.lastName, requester.firstName, impact.impactName, training_requirements.TimeNeeded, ";
    $query .=   "priority.priority, training_requirements.Notes ";
    $query .= "FROM ";
    $query .=   "training_requirements, impact, impacted_employees, location, mechanism, requester, priority ";
    $query .= "WHERE impact.impactId = training_requirements.impactId ";
    $query .=   "AND impacted_employees.groupId = training_requirements.impEmpId ";
    $query .=   "AND location.locationId = training_requirements.trainLocId ";
    $query .=   "AND mechanism.mechId = training_requirements.mechId ";
    $query .=   "AND requester.requesterId = training_requirements.requesterId ";
    $query .=   "AND priority.id = training_requirements.Priority ";
    $query .=   "AND training_requirements.Closed = $closed ";
    $query .=   "AND training_requirements.Deleted = 0";

    // run the query
    $result = executeQuery($connection, $query);

    // process the query
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($resource = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if (empty($thKey)) {
                foreach($resource as $key => $value) {
                    $thKey[] = $key;
                }
            }
            $data .= '<tr>';
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($resource); $i++) {
                if ($firstRow) {
                    // create the header
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($resource); $j++) {                 
                        $data .= '<th>';
                        $data .= $thKey[$j];
                        $data .= '</th>';
                    }
                    $data .= '</tr><tr>';
                    $firstRow = FALSE;
                }
                $data .= '<td>';
                if (isset($resource[$thKey[$i]])) {
                    $data .= $resource[$thKey[$i]]; 
                } else {
                    $data .= '&nbsp;';  
                }
                $data .= '</td>';
            }
            $data .= '</tr>';
        }
        $data .= '</table>';
        echo $data;
    }

    //header('Content-type: application/excel');
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.xls");
    //header("Pragma: no-cache");
    //header("Expires: 0");
?>
```

The code continues on to allow me to display the results in a browser. I get a proper looking table in Firefox. When I un-comment the header statements at the bottom, I get a blank Excel file. No cells, no nothing.

Using Excel 2007(12.0.6715.5000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6721.5000), PHP 5.4.24, and MySQL 5.5.40. Using plugins and libraries is not an option.

Vern

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you're NOT generating an excel file. you're generating html and LYING about it being excel... and you're also just assuming the query succeeded. if it returns no rows, or fails outright, you output nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

your code is just fech data from MySQL and not make any excel file .

here you are a great class for making execl file

with pure XML code without any extension

```
<?php

/********************************/
/* Code By Mr Korosh Raoufi     */
/* WwW.k2-4u.CoM                */
/********************************/


/**
 * Simple excel generating from PHP5
 *
 * @package Utilities
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * @author Oliver Schwarz <oliver.schwarz@gmail.com>
 * @version 1.0
 */

/**
 * Generating excel documents on-the-fly from PHP5
 * 
 * Uses the excel XML-specification to generate a native
 * XML document, readable/processable by excel.
 * 
 * @package Utilities
 * @subpackage Excel
 * @author Oliver Schwarz <oliver.schwarz@vaicon.de>
 * @version 1.1
 * 
 * @todo Issue #4: Internet Explorer 7 does not work well with the given header
 * @todo Add option to give out first line as header (bold text)
 * @todo Add option to give out last line as footer (bold text)
 * @todo Add option to write to file
 */
class Excel_XML
{

    /**
     * Header (of document)
     * @var string
     */
        private $header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"%s\"?\>\n<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">";

        /**
         * Footer (of document)
         * @var string
         */
        private $footer = "</Workbook>";

        /**
         * Lines to output in the excel document
         * @var array
         */
        private $lines = array();

        /**
         * Used encoding
         * @var string
         */
        private $sEncoding;

        /**
         * Convert variable types
         * @var boolean
         */
        private $bConvertTypes;

        /**
         * Worksheet title
         * @var string
         */
        private $sWorksheetTitle;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * The constructor allows the setting of some additional
         * parameters so that the library may be configured to
         * one's needs.
         * 
         * On converting types:
         * When set to true, the library tries to identify the type of
         * the variable value and set the field specification for Excel
         * accordingly. Be careful with article numbers or postcodes
         * starting with a '0' (zero)!
         * 
         * @param string $sEncoding Encoding to be used (defaults to UTF-8)
         * @param boolean $bConvertTypes Convert variables to field specification
         * @param string $sWorksheetTitle Title for the worksheet
         */
        public function __construct($sEncoding = 'UTF-8', $bConvertTypes = false, $sWorksheetTitle = 'Table1')
        {
                $this->bConvertTypes = $bConvertTypes;
            $this->setEncoding($sEncoding);
            $this->setWorksheetTitle($sWorksheetTitle);
        }

        /**
         * Set encoding
         * @param string Encoding type to set
         */
        public function setEncoding($sEncoding)
        {
            $this->sEncoding = $sEncoding;
        }

        /**
         * Set worksheet title
         * 
         * Strips out not allowed characters and trims the
         * title to a maximum length of 31.
         * 
         * @param string $title Title for worksheet
         */
        public function setWorksheetTitle ($title)
        {
                $title = preg_replace ("/[\\\|:|\/|\?|\*|\[|\]]/", "", $title);
                $title = substr ($title, 0, 31);
                $this->sWorksheetTitle = $title;
        }

        /**
         * Add row
         * 
         * Adds a single row to the document. If set to true, self::bConvertTypes
         * checks the type of variable and returns the specific field settings
         * for the cell.
         * 
         * @param array $array One-dimensional array with row content
         */
        private function addRow ($array)
        {
            $cells = "";
                foreach ($array as $k => $v):
                        $type = 'String';
                        if ($this->bConvertTypes === true && is_numeric($v)):
                                $type = 'Number';
                        endif;
                        $v = htmlentities($v, ENT_COMPAT, $this->sEncoding);
                        $cells .= "<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"$type\">" . $v . "</Data></Cell>\n"; 
                endforeach;
                $this->lines[] = "<Row>\n" . $cells . "</Row>\n";
        }

        /**
         * Add an array to the document
         * @param array 2-dimensional array
         */
        public function addArray ($array)
        {
                foreach ($array as $k => $v)
                        $this->addRow ($v);
        }


        /**
         * Generate the excel file
         * @param string $filename Name of excel file to generate (...xls)
         */
        public function generateXML ($filename = 'excel-export')
        {
                // correct/validate filename
                $filename = preg_replace('/[^aA-zZ0-9\_\-]/', '', $filename);

                // deliver header (as recommended in php manual)
                header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=" . $this->sEncoding);
                header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $filename . ".xls\"");

                // print out document to the browser
                // need to use stripslashes for the damn ">"
                echo stripslashes (sprintf($this->header, $this->sEncoding));
                echo "\n<Worksheet ss:Name=\"" . $this->sWorksheetTitle . "\">\n<Table>\n";
                foreach ($this->lines as $line)
                        echo $line;

                echo "</Table>\n</Worksheet>\n";
                echo $this->footer;
        }

}

?>
```

usage:

```
$xls = new Excel_XML('UTF-8', false, 'title text');

$data = array(
    1 => array ('column1 text', 'coloumn2 text'),
    1 => array ('column1 text', 'coloumn2 text'),
    1 => array ('column1 text', 'coloumn2 text'),
);

$xls -> addArray($data);
$xls -> generateXML('file Name');  // its print code to browser use requred header to download
```

Comment: Thanks! Working on testing it.

Comment: If we put redirect after generating excel, it is not downloading `excel`. Any idea to put `header(location:test.php');` and both should be working?