# How can I redirect to a another page after using request download cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to asking one question how to redirect to another page after using `$this->response->download;` by cakephp 2 .I already use :

```
$this->response->download($new_file_name);
print($output);
$this->Flash->success(__('The file has been successfully export.'));
return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

but it not working well. Is it any another way ?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done, it's a limitation in how browser requests work. You can find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822732/929304).

> The common thing (e.g. in popular download sites) is the reverse: first you go to the "after" page and then the download starts.

So, redirect the user to where you want them to end up, and then serve the download.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,but not sure that will worked.

```
$download='no';
$this->response->download($new_file_name);
print($output);
$download='yes';
if($download=='yes')
{
return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
else 
echo 'sorry did not downloaded';
```