# PHP YII2 - is it possible to direct to certain page after download file?

Tags: php, yii2

i have a code like this :

```
public function downloadFile($name)
{   
    $storagePath = "/opt/tmp/";

    // check filename for allowed chars (do not allow ../ to avoid security issue: downloading arbitrary files)

    if (!is_file("$storagePath/$name")) {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The file does not exists.');
    }

    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile("$storagePath/$name", $name);
}
```

this code is successfully download `file`, but that's can't direct to certain page.

So i want, if i press `button` click, 
in `browser` is save file, in `web` is direct to certain page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect) maybe you can do this too.

Comment: You must do it in javascript

Comment: how i do it with javasript? i mean what step by step?

Comment: why this question mark as answered that? that's not the same case.