# How to redirect to another page after download using gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, gravity-forms-plugin

What I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect) is it is not possible or not ideal to download then redirect to another page. I use this [hook](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/) `gform_after_submission` to trigger php script download after user submitted the form. But after the download started the page doesn't redirect to another text/page/url just like what documentation does [here](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/configuring-confirmations-in-gravity-forms/). I guess that is because of the `header` function. So what could be the best way to achieve this? I have few options but there are few things that I need some answers:

1. *Use javascript to manually redirect after download started* - but it seems i cant find a way to get the text/page/url that is set in the gravity form so I can use it in the javascript. Is there anyway to get it?
2. *Start the download script when it is already directed to other page.* - but how do I do that? Cant find any hooks that will tell me if Im already redirected to another page after submission.

Here is my download script:

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($final_file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($final_file));
```