# Return PDF and Redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I would like that, in a Laravel Controller, when I finish a method, it download a pdf and redirect to other route.

```
       $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)
          ->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
          ->setWarnings(false);
          return $pdf->download('deposit.pdf');

       return redirect()->route('devices.index');
```

If I put return in PDF, the method not redirect. If I remove "return", the PDF does not download. I tried the code below but it not working.

```
      return redirect()->response()->download($pdf)->route('devices.index');
```

Comment: The download response is a response. Once a response is sent a redirect response (which is also a response) cannot be sent. You need to handle the download differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP generate file for download then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822707/php-generate-file-for-download-then-redirect)

Comment: apokryfos is different. I am using Laravel, and it is in a Laravel Controller. Thanks for your answer.